# Use sed to change the stdout of crontab line

Tags: linux, bash, sed, cron

I try to add datetime on stdout of my script and redirect on a file.

I use the following command:

```
python3 script.py 2>&1 | sed -e "s/^/$(date + \%F \%T") /" > output.log
```

When I add this command in crontab editor, the sed command doesn't work!
Can you help me to understand the problem?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I added "\" near % because it seems a special character for crontab, but from command line I usely run:
`$(date + %F %T")`

Comment: Well, you could wrap your command in a script, but my main question is, why are you  not using python itself to change the date format and get rid of the **sed**?

Comment: Because I would like add the datetime also on stderr lines (redirected on stdout).
Do you know a better mehod to do it?

Comment: Can you share your Python script?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some quoting issues.  If I'm understanding the intent correctly, I think you want this:

```
python3 script.py 2>&1 | sed -e "s/^/$(date "+ %F %T")/" > output.log
```

Within the command substitution ( `$(...)` ) you can have another set of quotes.  It is like running the command on its own and using the output.  Your original command substitution command was:

```
date + \%F \%T"
```

With the extra quote on the end, the `)` is not registered as terminating the command substitution, so it actually does not terminate which is obviously a syntax error.

I think what you were trying to do was escape the spaces which would remove the need for the extra quotes like this:

```
date\ +\ %F\ %T
```

Check out shellcheck.net for some help with syntax errors, and general advice.  You can also download the program and use it directly on the terminal.

Comment: Thank you very much! shellcheck.net is veri useful!
I had the syntax error, but % is a special character for crontab, so it doesn't work with or without them.

Comment: @M.Love You could use the crontab to execute a script rather than this command directly.  Then, put what you need into a script, and you won't have to worry about crontab characters.